# Filter Asp.netcore logs in Log4Net

Tags: asp.net-core, log4net, log4net-configuration

I am using ASP.NET Core and have created a Log4net logging provider.

My current log4net.config file looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net debug="true">
  <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="logs\\" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <DatePattern value="yyyy\\\\MM\\\\dd'.inf.log'" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="false" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] &lt;%property{auth}&gt; - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender ref="HangfireLoggerAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="logs\HangfireLog.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
  </root>
  <logger additivity="false" name="Hangfire">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="HangfireLoggerAppender" />
  </logger>
</log4net>
```

The log is showing A LOT of asp.net core junk. SQL Logs ect.

I would like to filter out :
Microsoft.AspNetCore.* 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.*

How do I do this with Log4net?

Answer (score 1):

you need to configure logging on your WebHostBuilder as follows :
[Program.cs -> BuildWebHost(string[] args) ]

```
  return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
         ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
             {   logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                 logging.AddFilter("Microsoft.AspNetCore", LogLevel.Information);
                 logging.AddFilter(" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore", LogLevel.Information);
                 logging.AddConsole();
                 logging.AddDebug();
             })
        .Build();
```

You call the logging.AddFilter method specifying the namespace as first parameter and LogLevel as the second parameter.

This can be also done using configuration in appsettings.json file if you don't want to do in code. You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x#log-filtering)